# What does LOCAL do in Postscript?

Tags: dictionary, postscript

In [Thinking in Postscript](http://wwwcdf.pd.infn.it/localdoc/tips.pdf) (pdf), Chapter 5, exercise 3 (pp. 64-65) asks the reader to refactor this code to not store any dictionary entries:

```
36 750 moveto /Times-Roman 24 selectfont
% works like “show”, leaving current point at proper location
/ushow
% linethickness lineposition (words) ushow -
{ %def
  LOCAL begin
    /text exch def
    /linepos exch def
    /linethick exch def
    gsave
      0 linepos rmoveto
      text stringwidth rlineto
      linethick setlinewidth stroke
    grestore
    text show
  end
} dup 0 4 dict put def
0.5 -4 (test underlined text) ushow
```

My question is about `LOCAL`.  Ghostscript runs this code without error, and yet `LOCAL` is not:

- Defined in the exercise
- Documented in the Postcript Language Reference, third edition
- Documented in PostScript Language Tutorial and Cookbook

**What, in PostScript, is `LOCAL`?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is nothing defined. The code is a bit sneaky as the code **dup 0 4 dict put def** will take the executable and replace the LOCAL with the result of **4 dict**. The executable block (stuff between {}) is copied mainly because put returns nothing. Since its a reference to the same block your left over with

```
/ushow {-dict- begin ...rest of the executable...} def
```

This is all valid because LOCAL is never used anywhere (it is destroyed before its used). It would not matter what you use in place of LOCAL.

Comment: I had no idea a PS program could or would modify an executable array.  That _is_ sneaky.  Excellent answer, thanks!

Comment: Hey, wait.  This means that PostScript is like LISP: _Code is just data that you execute_.  And manipulate, if you want.

Comment: @WayneConrad see [my answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22240595/733077) for another example of modifying a procedure array in PS. It's a very flexible+powerful capability.

Answer (score 2):

As joojaa correctly explains, `LOCAL` is not defined to anything which is ok since it is replaced before executing. It parses as an executable name during construction of the procedure body (array) and its use here is just to allocate a slot in the array. It could actually be any type, and I've often seen (and written) `{ 0 begin ...}` for the same purpose. Using a name lets you give more semantic information to a human reader of the code. I've also seen it written `{ DICT begin ... }` [Here](http://code.google.com/p/xpost/downloads/detail?name=mat.ps) in my matrix functions, I called it `STATICDICT`, apparently.

There is a convention of using all upper-case for any *meta-syntactical* tokens like this. It is a nametype token, but meta-syntactically, it refers to a dicttype object to be filled-in later. There's no need (nor even any mechanism) to declare what you're doing for the benefit of the interpreter, but there is much to be gained by preferring `DICT` over `0`. Again, since it will be completely replaced, you could also use a literal name `/LOCAL` to try to, idunno, relieve the next noob to read your code from the wild-goose-chase of looking for where `LOCAL` is defined?? To this end, I've also written simply `DUMMY` for token *to-be-filled-in-later*. I suppose the choice among these terms is a matter of style or audience or some other intangible quality. sigh... or just a matter of context.

There is another style that works well for making dynamic substitutions in procedure bodies. By placing the dictionary on the dictstack and naming it (within itself, so it's a closed namespace), we can refer to it with an `//immediate` name

```
4 dict begin
/mydict currentdict def
/proc {
    //mydict begin
    ...
    end
}
```

and then remove the dictionary before defining.

```
end def
```

Thus defining the procedure normally (in the outer-level dictionary (unnamed here, presumably `userdict`)), but with the dictionary embedded *by name*, from having been available by that name while the procedure body was scanned.

This can be extended to more procedures sharing the same private dictionary by juggling the dict off of the stack for each definition.

```
/enddefbegin { currentdict 3 1 roll end def begin } def

4 dict begin
/mydict currentdict def

/proc1 {
    //mydict begin
    ...
    end
} enddefbegin

/proc2 {
    //mydict begin
    ...
    end
} enddefbegin

end
```

The `enddefbegin end` at the end can of course be simplified to `end def`.

One caveat. The dictionary created this way is recursively contained with itself. Do not try to print it with ghostscript's `===` operator!

Comment: I've started to use `-777` for this sort of dummy token, because it's sooo ugly it just screams off of the screen as something weird going on.

Answer (score 1):

Pg 133 of the "Blue Book" has a slightly easier example of the same technique:

```
/sampleproc 
{ 0 begin 
  /localvariable 6 def 
  end 
} def 
/sampleproc load 0 1 dict put
```

Here the procedure is defined before it is modified. It's a little easier to wrap your mind around. In the original post, the trickiest part for me was the "dup" because I didn't realize that the array on the stack is not an array precisely, it's an array reference (I was thinking copy-by-value, it functions copy-by-reference), so the "put" in the original code affects the array with the first reference (which is consequently consumed from the stack), and the second is used to define the procedure. It was a Newbie mistake, but maybe other newbies can learn from it:

Stack Progression:

```
...                                               % fast forward
1. ushow --array-- --array-- 0 4 dict | put def   % dict creates a dictionary
2. ushow --array-- --array-- 0 --dict-- | put def % put arrives on stack
3. ushow --array-- --array-- 0 --dict-- put | def % put consumes the array 0 and dict
4. ushow --array-- | def                          % def arrives on stack
5. ushow --array-- def                            % def consumes the remaining tokens
6.
```

Sorry for what is probably incorrect notation, I just stared at this for a while, and figured I might be able to save someone a little stare-time. Please let me know if there are any errors or misleading statements that I should fix.